# React component not re-rendering after useQuery

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, graphql, apollo-client, apollo-server

I'm using useQuery from ApolloClint to fetch data from a database. The problem I'm getting is that the result I'm getting from graphql seems to not affect the depencey inside the useEffect  and therefore fail to re-render after the data has been received on the front end.
I have this React component:

```
export default function PrivateRoute({
  exact,
  path,
  component: Component,
  ...rest
}: Props): ReactElement {
  let [status, setStatus] = useState(false);
  const { data, error, loading } = useQuery(GET_CURRENT_USER);

  useEffect(() => {
    data?.id && setStatus(true);
  }, [data]);

  if (error) console.log(error);
  if (loading) return <Spinner></Spinner>;

  return (
    <Route
      {...rest}
      render={(props) =>
        status ? (
          <>
            <Navbar></Navbar>
            <Component {...props} />
          </>
        ) : (
          <Redirect
            to={{ pathname: "/login", state: { from: props.location } }}
          />
        )
      }
    />
  );
}
```

I understand that useEffect fires before useQuery is done and not at the first render "status" is false, but shouldn't it re-render after "data" object has changed since I placed in the useEffect dependecy?

Here, I expect that if there is a user (data is not undefined), the Route will return the first option of the condition.

However, data is returned eventually by GraphQL, but react doesn't do a re-render.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, if I move the conditional for rendering inside render=((props) => ...)} it works.

```
export default function PrivateRoute({
  exact,
  path,
  component: Component,
  ...rest
}: Props): ReactElement {
  const { data, error, loading } = useQuery(GET_CURRENT_USER);

  if (error) console.log(error);
  if (loading) return <Spinner></Spinner>;

  return (
    <Route
      {...rest}
      render={(props) => {
        return data ? (
          <>
            <Navbar></Navbar>
            <Component {...props} />
          </>
        ) : (
          <Redirect
            to={{ pathname: "/login", state: { from: props.location } }}
          />
        );
      }}
    />
  );
}
```